# How can import some sub-matrix (sub-array2D) and create a matrix (array2D) according to them with a nested loop in python

Tags: python, loops, import, nested, submatrix

I generated 4 sub-matrix(block) data and I want to import them to matrix "X"

```
   X = np.array((10,10))
```

> and they are sub-matrix

[sub-matrix into X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9LJW.png)

```
  row_number=[8,2]

  column_number=[6,4]

  n = (row_number).T@column_number
```

> My problem is How can import the below sub-matrices into matrix "X"

```
  for i in range(2):

      for j in range(2):

      B = np.reshape(norm.rvs(loc = 0, scale = 1, size = n[i][j]),(row_number[i], column_number[j]))
```

> thanks all for any help.